# Send email in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

So I have a rails application where a `recruiter` posts a job (recruiter `has_many jobs`, all associations are set up properly) and `users` are able to click on a apply button which send an email using Action Mailer to the recruiter for that specific job.

`User` and `Recruiter` are two separate models created by Devise.

Jobs was generated by `rails g scaffold Job .....`

Heres what I have so far:

ApplyMailer.rb:

```
class ApplyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_apply(job)
    @user = current_user
    @job = job
    mail to: @job.recruiter.email,
         subject: "Someone whats to appy for #{@job.title}"
  end
end
```

Jobs#show view:

```
<%= button_to(apply_path, class:"btn btn-info") do %>
   Apply
<% end %>
```

Jobs_controller.rb:

```
def sendemail
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  ApplyMailer.new_apply(@job).deliver_now
end
```

Routes.rb

```
post '/apply' => 'jobs#sendemail'
```

First of all I'm not sure if I'm doing this the correct way for what I'm trying to achieve. What I'm trying to do is:

So the button is on the `jobs#show` page, it should take that `job` as an argument and send an email to the `associated recruiter`. The `current_user (User model)` would be the user trying to apply for the job, so in the email view it would say the name of the user(check below).

new_apply.html.erb:

```
<div class="">
  <h2><%= @user.profile.name %> want to apply for the job</h2>
</div>
```

The question is after the button is pressed how could an email be sent to the `recruiter` about the `job` post. The email needs to contain the `current_user` name and email. Above is what I have tried, but no email is getting sent.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask the question rather than telling us what you did !

Comment: You need to pass in the user, the mailer doesn't know what `current_user` is

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Should we guess your question ?

Comment: @GurmukhSingh Are there any errors in Rails log file? Do you have sendmail or something similar installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller

```
def create
  # creating your job
  if @job.create
    ApplyMailer.new_apply(current_user, job).deliver_now
  else
    # what you want
  end
end
```

and add to mailer your user

```
class ApplyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_apply(user, job)
    @user = user
    @job = job
    mail to: @job.recruiter.email,
         subject: "Someone whats to appy for #{@job.title}"
  end
end
```

BTW

you have to use routes according to CRUD according to [Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Answer (score 1):

Use Action Mailer for Sending Mail.

```
  class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site',
         template_path: 'notifications',
         template_name: 'another')
  end
end
```

For more information use this link:-

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html